# Force field to update on keystroke / change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently attempting to design an online form where staff can submit their weekly hours.

I've quite successfully designed a table / form where they can input their hours for the week and eventually they will send the form to a specified email address.

When they enter their hours, I want a row of fields at the bottom of the table to update and keep a running total for how many hours they've worked that day and a final total to display how many hours they've worked that week. I could just add them up back-end and have them sent with the email, however I would quite like them to automatically update as they're entering their hours so that they can see a total they've worked.

This is what the form looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdtAD.png

At the moment I think my PHP implementation would work, but because it requires the page to be refreshed and refreshing clears the values, you would never see the total.

```
        <div class="totals">
          <?php
            if (isset($_GET['m1']) && isset($_GET['m2'])) 
            {
              $num1 = $_GET['m1'];
              $num2 = $_GET['m2'];
              $sum = $num1 + $num2;
            }
          ?>
        <p><?= $sum ?></p>
```

Is there anyway to update that `$sum` value whenever the `m1` or `m2` value are altered?

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah you'll need javascript for that. Try using some change events and stuff. I'd recommend Vue but I'm under the impression that you're new to programming so this would confuse you more right now.

Comment: Not new to programming, just limited to PHP, HTML and CSS. I'll take a look at javascript change events then. Thanks.